# Pygame making an object chase the cursor

Tags: python, pygame

Been at this for the past few hours, trying to make a small program where an image chases the cursor around. So far I've managed to make it so that the image is directly on top of the cursor and follows it around that way. However what I need is for the image to actually "chase" the cursor, so it would need to initially be away from it then run after it until it's then on top of the mouse.

Basically hit a wall with whats going wrong and what to fix up, here's what I've gotten so far:

```
from __future__ import division
import pygame
import sys
import math
from pygame.locals import *


class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('ball.png')
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 1

    def draw(self, surface):
        mosx = 0
        mosy = 0
        x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mosx = (x - self.x)
        mosy = (y - self.y)
        self.x = 0.9*self.x + mosx
        self.y = 0.9*self.y + mosy
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
        pygame.display.update()


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
cat = Cat()
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    cat.draw(screen)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
    Clock.tick(40)
```

Probably not in the best shape of coding, been messing with this for just over 5 hours now. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Sadly, runnable code snippets only work for JS/HTML code, not Python, so just format Python as code, not as a runnable snippet. (I've edited it for you.)

Comment: Thanks! First time posting, wasn't quite sure, but I appreciate it :)

Comment: I don't understand what many of those lines of code are supposed to do. Why are you doing `self.x += 2` twice, or even once? Why are you storing `mosx` and `mosy` as instance attributes when they're only used locally in `draw`? And most of all, what is `.9 * x + mosx` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Also, do you want the cat to move at a fixed speed, or to move faster the farther away the cursor is?

Comment: The self.x+= 2 parts were originally there so I could test it, I just tried removing them and nothing was changed. I'll toss an edit up there to remove them. Storing of mosx and mosy was also a mistake on my part, those should be brought down to draw. Finally, the .9 * x + mosx part is me trying to slow down the speed of the ball and adjust it's direction so that it will head towards the cursor, hopefully that clarifies things?

Comment: Edited the code above, what's there now is what I've been working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the cat to move at a fixed speed, like X pixels per tick, you need to pick a new position X pixels toward the mouse cursor. (If you instead want the cat to move slower the closer it gets, you'd instead pick a position a certain % of the way between the current position and the mouse cursor. If you want it to move faster the closer it gets, you need to divide instead of multiply. And so on. But let's stick with the simple one first.)

Now, how do you move X pixels toward the mouse cursor? The usual way of describing this is: You find the unit vector in the direction from the current position to the cursor, then multiply it by X, and that gives you the steps to add. And you can reduce that to nothing fancier than a square root:

```
# Vector from me to cursor
dx = cursor_x - me_x
dy = cursor_y - me_y

# Unit vector in the same direction
distance = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
dx /= distance
dy /= distance

# speed-pixel vector in the same direction
dx *= speed
dy *= speed

# And now we move:
me_x += dx
me_y += dy
```

Note that `me_x` and `me_y` are going to be floating-point numbers, not integers. That's a good thing; when you move 2 pixels northeast per step, that's 1.414 pixels north and 1.414 pixels east. If you round that down to 1 pixel each step, you're going to end up moving 41% slower when going diagonally than when going vertically, which would look kind of silly.

Comment: Thanks! Now the image actually does chase the cursor, only issue I'm running into is that the image moves really really slowly, I've tried plugging values in for speed, from 5 all the way up to 200. Second issue I'm running into is when the cursor goes above the image, especially at higher speeds, the image freaks out and somehow shows itself twice, on opposite sides of the cursor. Any ideas whats going on?

Comment: With `speed` at 200, that's 200 pixels every 1/40th of a second. So on, say, a 1920x1680 screen, it should cross the whole screen in 1/4th of a second. The fact that it's jumping around implies the problem might be that you've got the wrong variable in there somewhere. The obvious thing to do is log all the values at each step. `dx` and `dy` should be a few hundred pixels after the first step, somewhere between -1 and 1 after the second, between -speed and speed after the third; the first one that's not what it should be, that narrows down the problem.

Comment: haha, figured out the problem. Turns out I had dx for the speed part both times, a quick change to dy for one and it works wonderfully! Thank you so much :)