# Chase function taking into account the rectangles ahead of it in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have two animals, Cat and Mouse. Cat has to chase the mouse.

I wrote this function based on this post: [Pygame making an object chase the cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664306/pygame-making-an-object-chase-the-cursor).

```
def chase(self):
        dx = mouse.rect.x - self.rect.x
        dy = mouse.rect.y - self.rect.y
        distance = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
        dx /= distance
        dy /= distance
        dx *= 8
        dy *= 8
        self.move(dx, dy)
        pygame.display.update()
```

But my screen looks like this:

```
level_definition = """
WWWWWWWWW
        W
W W     W
W W  P  W
WWWWWWWWW
"""
```

So there are walls in between center of the screen. How can I change the function so that it takes into the account the walls, when the cat is chasing the mouse?

**Edit:**

Thanks to JoranBeasley, I know that I need to use A*search algorithm to find the path. Found this link: http://code.google.com/p/find-a-way/downloads/list. It contains the solver.py which contains the A*star algorithm class which can find the path. Not sure how to incorporate it into this example. Not sure how to input the barriers in to the Star class.

Solver looks like this:

```
class Star(object):
    """This class is the astar algorithm itself.  The goal is to make it
    flexible enough that it can be used in isolation."""
    def __init__(self,start,end,move_type,barriers):
        """Arguments start and end are coordinates to start solving from and to.
        move_type is a string cooresponding to the keys of the ADJACENTS and
        HEURISTICS constant dictionaries. barriers is a set of cells which the
        agent is not allowed to occupy."""
        self.start,self.end = start,end
        self.moves = ADJACENTS[move_type]
        self.heuristic = HEURISTICS[move_type]
        self.barriers = barriers
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        """Initialize sets,dicts and others"""
        self.closed_set = set((self.start,)) #Set of cells already evaluated
        self.open_set   = set() #Set of cells to be evaluated.
        self.came_from = {} #Used to reconstruct path once solved.
        self.gx = {self.start:0} #Cost from start to current position.
        self.hx = {} #Optimal estimate to goal based on heuristic.
        self.fx = {} #Distance-plus-cost heuristic function.
        self.current = self.start
        self.current = self.follow_current_path()
        self.solution = []
        self.solved = False

    def get_neighbors(self):
        """Find adjacent neighbors with respect to how our agent moves."""
        neighbors = set()
        for (i,j) in self.moves:
            check = (self.current[0]+i,self.current[1]+j)
            if check not in (self.barriers|self.closed_set):
                neighbors.add(check)
        return neighbors

    def follow_current_path(self):
        """In the very common case of multiple points having the same heuristic
        value, this function makes sure that points on the current path take
        presidence.  This is most obvious when trying to use astar on an
        obstacle free grid."""
        next_cell = None
        for cell in self.get_neighbors():
            tentative_gx = self.gx[self.current]+1
            if cell not in self.open_set:
                self.open_set.add(cell)
                tentative_best = True
            elif cell in self.gx and tentative_gx < self.gx[cell]:
                tentative_best = True
            else:
                tentative_best = False

            if tentative_best:
                x,y = abs(self.end[0]-cell[0]),abs(self.end[1]-cell[1])
                self.came_from[cell] = self.current
                self.gx[cell] = tentative_gx
                self.hx[cell] = self.heuristic(x,y)
                self.fx[cell] = self.gx[cell]+self.hx[cell]
                if not next_cell or self.fx[cell]<self.fx[next_cell]:
                    next_cell = cell
        return next_cell

    def get_path(self,cell):
        """Recursively reconstruct the path. No real need to do it recursively."""
        if cell in self.came_from:
            self.solution.append(cell)
            self.get_path(self.came_from[cell])

    def evaluate(self):
        """Core logic for executing the astar algorithm."""
        if self.open_set and not self.solved:
            for cell in self.open_set:
                if (self.current not in self.open_set) or (self.fx[cell]<self.fx[self.current]):
                    self.current = cell
            if self.current == self.end:
                self.get_path(self.current)
                self.solved = True
            self.open_set.discard(self.current)
            self.closed_set.add(self.current)
            self.current = self.follow_current_path()
        elif not self.solution:
            self.solution = "NO SOLUTION"
```

Edit:

Error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-128:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1082, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Dropbox/Pygame/Test.py", line 198, in printit
    cat.chase()
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Dropbox/Pygame/Test.py", line 65, in chase
    best_path = get_current_best_path()
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Dropbox/Pygame/Test.py", line 153, in get_current_best_path
    return MyAStar(start_pt,end_pt,barriers).get_best_path()
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Dropbox/Pygame/Test.py", line 142, in __init__
    self.setup()
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Dropbox/Pygame/solver.py", line 64, in setup
    self.current = self.follow_current_path()
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Dropbox/Pygame/solver.py", line 83, in follow_current_path
    for cell in self.get_neighbors():
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Dropbox/Pygame/solver.py", line 73, in get_neighbors
    if check not in (self.barriers|self.closed_set):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'set'
```

Code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/omqj5121ev43mxc/Test.py?dl=0

Comment: you use an a* algorithm ... in which wall tiles have infinite weight http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-star

Comment: @JoranBeasley can u elaborate more?

Comment: you can also do things like move in a random direction when you hit a wall or something ... or just let it get stuck ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley at the moment, it gets stuck at the wall and doesn't move. moving in an random direction won't help because cat will end up in the same place.. Can show how to implement A-star search algorithm in this case?

Comment: so a* will cure that ... but its much more complicated than a simple chase function (not too complicated ... its one of the simpler path finding algorithms)  ... but really alot of the time its not a problem if something gets stuck until you are back in its field of view (PS downvote wasnt me)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64049/discussion-between-lakesh-and-joran-beasley).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
from solver import Star
class MyAStar(Star):
    def __init__(self,start_pt,end_pt,barriers):
      self.start,self.end = start_pt,end_pt
      self.moves = ADJACENTS[move_type]
      self.barriers = barriers
      self.setup()

    def heuristic(self,x,y):
      return (x-self.end[0])**2 + (y - self.end[0])**2
    def get_best_path(self):
      self.evaluate()
      return self.solution

def get_current_best_path():
  start_pt,end_pt = (enemy.x,enemy.y),(mouse.x,mouse.y) 
  barriers = [(barrier1.x,barrier1.y),...,(barrierN.x,barrierN.y)]
  return Star(start_pt,end_pt,barriers).get_best_path()

best_path = get_current_best_path()
moves = 0
RECALC_PATH_COUNT = 5 #recalculate path every five moves
while best_path: # you would do this in the chase function
  next_move = best_path.pop()
  moves += 1
  if moves > RECALC_PATH_COUNT:
    moves = 0
    best_path = get_current_best_path()
```

Comment: how do you execute the bestpath, after getting it?

Comment: best path is just a list of moves... so just pop them off the front and move to that position ...

Comment: it think it should return MyAStar(start_pt,end_pt,barriers).get_best_path() for get_current_best_path

Comment: self.moves = ADJACENTS[move_type]
NameError: global name 'ADJACENTS' is not defined how to solve this?

Comment: you have to define that .. follow the example in the original code (but your adjacency list would be different)

Comment: can u explain what the adjacents and heuristic are for? how can i change it to my example?

Comment: adjacents seems to describe allowed moves ... you probably just want to assign the ones from rook or maybe queen ... rook can only move up down left right, while queen can move diagonally ... you should not need to worry about heuristics as I provided a function for that in my example ... but essentially it is the estimated cost from that node to the goal

Comment: thanks for the help so far. It gives me a new error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'set'. Have attached my code and the error in the main question. Have a look..